# Safely modify a replicated column's data type in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

What command would I execute to safely change (i.e. from int to bigint) a replicated column's data type in SQL Server 2005?

The column is not a key. There is a non-clustered index on the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
    ALTER COLUMN myIntCol bigint
```

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152562.aspx):

> By default, the following schema
>   changes made at a Publisher running
>   SQL Server are replicated to all SQL
>   Server Subscribers:
>
> - ALTER TABLE
> - ALTER VIEW
> - ALTER PROCEDURE
> - ALTER FUNCTION
> - ALTER TRIGGER

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that there is an index on the column, and the command above is producing an error when executed. Would I have to remove the index?